# Capture javascript event in IE Mobile

Tags: javascript, dom-events, ie-mobile

I need to detect the id of the element that generated an `onchange` event.

This code work in most **modern browsers**:

```
<input type="text" onchange="return onchange_handler(event);"

function onchange_handler(event) {
    var id = event.target ? event.target.id : event.srcElement.id;
    ...
    return false;
}
```

But it does not work in **IE Mobile**.

I have tried the following code, and at least the event is fired and the handler function is called, but `window.event` is not available when event handler is called:

```
<input type="text" onchange="return onchange_handler();"

function onchange_handler() {
    var event = window.event; // <= evaluated as UNDEFINED
    var id = event.target ? event.target.id : event.srcElement.id;
    ...
    return false;
}
```

Is there any way to obtain a reference to the fired event?  Or an alternative approach to know the id of the element that caused the event.

Comment: In every browser the `change` event on textboxes is only fired when the user focuses away from the textbox (i.e., on `blur`). Have you verified IE Mobile has the same characteristic?

Comment: Yes, the event is fired even in IE Mobile, but I can't find a way to access the event (window.event) variable.

Comment: Do *any* events work on IE Mobile? From what I can see here: http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:qpi5snb2FLMJ:https://connect.microsoft.com/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx%3FFeedbackID%3D312339%26SiteID%3D502+%22IE+Mobile%22+OR+%22Mobile+IE%22+events it seems there is a serious lack of basic DOM event support on that browser.

Comment: So both - event passed as a fist argument AND `window.event` are not available when event handler is called?

Comment: Yes, some events work. In fact the onchange_handler in the example is called, but there is no access to window.event.  There is no first argument in IE Mobile, because if I use it, the handler function is not called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround would be to pass the element to the callback: (untested)

```
<input type="text" id="mytextbox" onchange="return onchange_handler(this);"

function onchange_handler(element) {
    var id = element.id;
    ...
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works but it forces me to keep two versions of the scripts.  I accept your answer as it is probably the only solution.